# How to set images in Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm converting android native code into Cordova plugin. In native i'm using following code to set the image in Floating Action Button

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        floatingActionButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_record, getTheme()));
    } else {
        floatingActionButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_record));
    }
```

My doubt is, In android we will use `R.drawable.XXXXXX` for setting the image. Like wise how we can set the image in cordova plugin and where we have to store the images (Like drawable folders in android native)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example from [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/src/android/InAppBrowser.java#L635-L642) plugin

```
Resources activityRes = cordova.getActivity().getResources();
int backResId = activityRes.getIdentifier("ic_action_previous_item", "drawable", cordova.getActivity().getPackageName());
Drawable backIcon = activityRes.getDrawable(backResId);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
    back.setBackground(null);
else
    back.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
back.setImageDrawable(backIcon);
```

The images are copied using the [resource-file tag](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/plugin.xml#L58-L61) in plugin.xml

```
<resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png" target="res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png" />
<resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png" target="res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png" />
<resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png" target="res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png" />
<resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png" target="res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable support :-)